# Decrypted Image from hex string cannot be open

Tags: python, encryption

I have a question regarding my two codes I'm working on. The purpose of this program is to encrypt an image of .png format. Then I'll work on displaying the encrypted image as a bitmap image. And finally, I would like to decrypt it into its original image.

So far, I'm simply working on taking the image -> converting it into hex -> encrypting by DES in ECB mode and decrypting it back.

However, I have an issue when I try to display the image after it's decrypted! The code itself is fine and doesn't give any Traceback.

But the image which was saved and I intend to open gives the following error:

> "Could not load image 'newSavedImage.png'. Fatal error reading PNG
>   image file: Not a PNG file"

```
from PIL import Image
import binascii
import blockcipher as bc

def load_image(img_name):
    with open(img_name, 'rb') as f:
        img_obj = f.read()

    img_obj = binascii.hexlify(img_obj)
#    binascii.a2b_hex(img_obj.replace(' ', ''))
    return img_obj


def save_image(img_obj):
    temp = open("newSavedImage.png", "wb") #  with original image extension

    #  write into the object by decoding base64 object
    temp.write(binascii.unhexlify(img_obj))
    temp.close()   

def choose_encr(img_obj):
    key, encr_img = bc.myDESencr(img_obj, 1)
    encr_img = binascii.hexlify(encr_img)
    return key, encr_img

def decrypt(encr_obj, key):
    orig_img = bc.myDESdecr(encr_obj, key, 1)
    orig_img = binascii.hexlify(orig_img)
    return orig_img

if __name__ =="__main__":
    img_str = 'pic3.png' #  the img is in my working dir
    img = load_image(img_str)
#    save_image(img)
    key, enc = choose_encr(img)
    img = decrypt(enc, key)
    save_image(img)
```

and this is my code for DES encryption I use

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3, DES
from Crypto import Random
import Crypto.Util

#  mode is integer values ranging from 1 to 4
def myDESencr(orig_image, mode):

    #  generate random key
    key = Random.get_random_bytes(8)

    #  pad if not byte size of % 8
    orig_image = pad(orig_image)

    #  instantiation with the right mode
    if mode == 1:
        des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)

    encrypted_image = des.encrypt(orig_image)
    return key, encrypted_image

def myDESdecr(encr_image, key, mode):
    if mode == 1:
        des = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_ECB)
        orig_image = des.decrypt(encr_image)
    return orig_image 

def pad(orig_image):
    while len(orig_image) % 8 != 0:
        orig_image += b'\0'
    return orig_image
```

So, the gist of my issue that after I decrypt the encrypted hex string and save it, it will give me a fatal error for .png images.

Also, when I save the string right after I invoke load_image(img_name) and then save it, it works fine.

Comment: Please always post the Traceback (formatted as code) if there is one. Have you tried to create a [mcve]?

Comment: [Why “Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: @wwii Yes, I tried my code on a simple string which outputs correct results.

Comment: On decryption you must undo all the processing steps **in the reverse order** that was done upon encryption. For encryption you do these steps: pad -> encrypt -> hexlify. Therefore on decrypt you must do unhexlify -> decrypt -> unpad.